# What is wrong with this regex email pattern?

Tags: regex, email-validation

I have got a pattern to validate a HTML5 email field:

`[A-z\u00c0-\u017e0-9._%+-]+@[A-z\u00c0-\u017e0-9.-]+\.[A-z]{2,3}$`

It should allow European characters as well as numbers and other symbols.

I am getting this error:

```
A part followed by '@' should not contain the symbol 'á'
```

It allows `abc@défg.com` but not `ábc@defg.com`

Is anyone able to help? Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use `type="email"`?

Comment: doesn't allow more than 3 characters in the TLD. Also, doesn't allow non-English characters in the TLD. The "European characters" don't actually cover Cyrillic or Greek. Doesn't support quotation marks as part of the name.

Comment: Removing the pattern and just using type="email" also gives the error "A part followed by '@' should not contain the symbol 'á'". Maybe this is just a limitation as I'm not sure international characters in email is widely supported. Need to do some more research. Thanks for your replies!

Comment: If this is not a typo - there is no `^` for the beginning of string, i.e. pattern will ignore invalid characters in the beginning